# how can i change the column order over the input or tkinter entry boxes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am searching for a way to change the columns of a dataframe via the input in the shell. I tried out several ways but none of them worked...
example:

```
l=[]
d=input()
l.append(d)
df.columns = l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the reason this example fails to work because it doesn't process multiple columns? If so, one way to do it is to force the end user to delimit their input with a character string. For example, if the user wanted columns a, b, and c, they might input

```
a, b, c
```

Where ', ' is the delimiter. d will still be assigned to string 'a, b, c', but

```
d.split(delimiter)
```

will split the string into a list. Then assign this list to df.columns like you currently do.
If instead you want the end user to use multiple inputs and not have a delimiter, just do

```
for old_column_name in df.columns:
    l.append(input())
```

to take an input for every column.